# ArgoCD history panel shows incorrect info for recent releases

Tags: kubernetes, argocd

The history page doesn't show the correct values for params (such as image.tag) after sync using the same Helm Chart version from a helm repo. All entries in the page display the same chart params. Consequently, the rollback function doesn't seems to work.

A list of the steps required to reproduce the issue. Best of all, give us the URL to a repository that exhibits this issue.

1. Update a parameter in values.yaml in a Helm Chart (image.tag, i.e.) without updating the Chart Version.
2. Package and Push the Helm Chart to a Chart Repo (Harbor, in my case), overwriting the existing one with the same version (0.1.0, i.e.)
3. Select an app which is pointing to that Helm Chart repo and "hard refresh" so Argo downloads the new chart (.tgz).
4. Manually sync the app (the diff shows that there is a new image.tag)
5. Verify that all the entries in history page display the same old version of the chart. (All history params is updated to the last version of the applied chart after the cache expires)
   6 (optional). If I decide to rollback to any version, it applies the same chart that is already deployed (and ignore the values shown on history).

A clear and concise description of what you expected to happen, that the history page shows all changes and that Argo could keep track of Charts changes, even with the same Chart version.

Below is a sample manifest that I've used to create my application:

```yaml
apiVersion: argoproj.io/v1alpha1
kind: Application
metadata:
  name: payoutmerchantsvc
  namespace: argocd
spec:
  project: default
  source:
    repoURL: <JFROG_HELM_REPO_URL>
    chart: payoutmerchantsvc-dev
    targetRevision: 1.0.*
    helm:
      releaseName: payoutmerchantsvc-dev5
  destination:
    server: "https://kubernetes.default.svc"
    namespace: payoutmerchantsvc
```

There was an issue on github raised for the same 2 years ago https://github.com/argoproj/argo-cd/pull/2849 which was closed but I'm still facing it.

I'm using ArgoCD app v2.6.3

Comment: Can you create a new GitHub issue with this information? https://github.com/argoproj/argo-cd/issues/

Comment: @crenshaw-dev Issue raised https://github.com/argoproj/argo-cd/issues/13006